# Why Apache is slow on LAN when serving for Android client?

Tags: php, android, apache, http, wamp

I'm currently developing PHP based service for very specific need. During development I tumbled to very strange problem (at least to me it is). I've already tried all the tricks that I know and googled like a crazy to find a solution but the problem still persists.

And now to the question or problem itself as you will! On my local area network (192.168.0.*) I have Apache based PHP server (WAMP) running on my laptop with Windows 8.1 OS. On same LAN I have also Android (Lollipop) based client that I'm using to connect and testing my service on this PHP server over HTTP. In addition I also have some other clients (Android KitKat and Linux BusyBox) on the same LAN that I occasionally use to test the service. Everything works fine when testing the PHP service on localhost but when I'm connecting to it from the Android client over LAN (using LAN ip) it takes almost 5 seconds to get the web page. Connecting web pages on internet works normally though so the problem is LAN (and ip) related. I've tested this over Android browser and also over curl. The problem exists with both Androids that I have connected to LAN (KitKat and Lollipop) but not with the BusyBox linux.

WAMP server is running Apache 2.4.9, PHP 5.5.12 and MySql 5.6.17. I use port 8080 for the web server. My webserver has ip address 192.168.0.101:8080 to which my Android client (ip 192.168.0.106) is connecting to. Ping from android to server is fast. HTTP for some reason is not. I have used linuxes before but I'm not very familiar with Android based ones so maybe there is something that I've missed...

This is the User-Agent header android sends to server:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; RR3281 Build/LMY49F)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/39.0.0.0
>   Safari/537.36"

I now added some extra logging to Apache server and it seems that the time taken to serve the request is the key here. So it's something on the Apache/PHP end of things. Why it only happens with Android is another thing... This problem occurs regardless if I'm serving PHP or plain HTML content.

So the question is why Apache server (WAMP) is serving slowly to Android client on LAN and preferably how to fix this?

Comment: How are using a wired connection to connect your Android device to the network? Does your device have an ethernet port?

Comment: Yes it has ethernet port. It is an RK 3281 based tablet device.

Comment: What's that? Got a link? Can you try wirelessly with a different Android device? This would help diagnose whether it's a problem with the ethernet connection on the device (which I find unusual) or your network setup.

Comment: Android device is connected to switch via Cat 5 cable. To which all the devices in LAN are connected to including the Cable modem which is used as default gateway.

Comment: Here are some related links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockchip_RK3288 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockchip

Comment: I tried with the other android device (KitKat) using WLAN instead and got same result with it. So the problem exists both in wired and wireless connections.

Comment: How are you testing the speed? Just using default browser and guessing or testing programmatically?

Comment: In addition to using browser => curl 192.168.0.101:8080 -w '%{time_starttransfer}'

Comment: With curl all other times are reasonable except starttransfer which takes 4 to 5 secs...

Comment: Haven't used any other speed testing methods this far. The same curl request run from my BusyBox client took about 0.8 second.

Comment: Hmm it is strange. I have not experienced any similar slowness with an Android device connecting via http on a local network so my guess is it's something with your webapp - I would experiment with the request headers, and see if your web server is responding differently to the different curl requests.

Comment: Sometimes if you change your PHP code to connect to MYSQL using `127.0.0.1` rather than `localhost` PHP and MYSQL get connected quicker as there is no need for a DNSCache lookup. Try that

Comment: I tried that but it did not help. And it would not explain why page loads fast with BusyBox client but not with Android one...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. Problem was caused by the WAMP server. I'm still not sure what the real problem was but I suspect it had something to do with modules WAMP was using... Anyway the problem was solved by replacing WAMP server with UniServer Zero server.

Thank to all of you taking the time to participate in this!